# How to configure JS-CSS-HTML Formatter so multiline if conditions are formatted correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, formatting, formatter

I am using the JSS-CSS-HTML formatter with an `'indent_size: 2'` but the formatter does not format multiline js if conditions properly. Is there a way to format the multiline if conditions such that auto indent does not apply to new break lines and are indented such that they only occur after the if parantheses?

**JS-CSS-HTML formatter gives script.js below:**

```
if (e.target.classList.contains('apple') &&
  !e.target.classList.contains('orange')) {
  console.log(e.target)
} else if (e.target.classList.contains('wheat') &&
  e.target.classList.contains('rice')) {
  console.log(e.target)
}
```

**want script.js below:**

```
if (e.target.classList.contains('apple') &&
    !e.target.classList.contains('orange')) {
      console.log(e.target)
} else if (e.target.classList.contains('wheat') &&
           e.target.classList.contains('rice')) {
             console.log(e.target)
}
```

**my formatter.json config file below:**

```
{
  "onSave": true,
  "javascript": {
    "indent_size": 2,
    "indent_char": " ",
    "eol": "auto",
    "preserve_newlines": true,
    "break_chained_methods": false,
    "max_preserve_newlines": 0,
    "space_in_paren": false,
    "space_in_empty_paren": false,
    "jslint_happy": false,
    "space_after_anon_function": false,
    "keep_array_indentation": false,
    "space_before_conditional": true,
    "unescape_strings": false,
    "wrap_line_length": 0,
    "e4x": false,
    "end_with_newline": false,
    "comma_first": false,
    "operator_position": "before-newline",
    "brace_style": "collapse-preserve-inline"
  },
  "css": {
    "indent_size": 2,
    "indentCharacter": " ",
    "indent_char": " ",
    "selector_separator_newline": true,
    "end_with_newline": false,
    "newline_between_rules": true,
    "eol": "\n"
  },
  "html": {
    "indent_inner_html": false,
    "indent_size": 2,
    "indent_char": " ",
    "indent_character": " "
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think mine is set up with what you're looking for.

```js
"javascript": {
    "indent_size": 4,
    "indent_char": " ",
    "eol": "auto",
    "preserve_newlines": true,
    "break_chained_methods": false,
    "max_preserve_newlines": 0,
    "space_in_paren": false,
    "space_in_empty_paren": false,
    "jslint_happy": false,
    "space_after_anon_function": false,
    "keep_array_indentation": false,
    "space_before_conditional": true,
    "unescape_strings": false,
    "wrap_line_length": 0,
    "e4x": false,
    "end_with_newline": false,
    "comma_first": false,
    "brace_style": "collapse-preserve-inline"
},
```